# CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver doesn't notify receiving SMS

Tags: ios, ios8, jailbreak, core-telephony

I have an app where I want to react when a SMS is received; up until iOS 7 this worked by registering to CTTelephonyCenter like this:

```
        id center = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
        CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(center,
                                     NULL,
                                     callback,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

and in the callback checking for kCTMessageReceivedNotification. This does not work in iOS 8 anymore, as I receive far less notification types than on iOS 7, and none related to message receiving.
I assume this is about a new entitlement, but could not figure yet if so, and what is the entitlement needed. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: How to add this observer? Do we need to import any framework? When I add above code, I get error "Implicit declaration of function CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault is invalid in c99,  conversion from int to id not allowed in arc,  CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver not valid in c99

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify notification name in fourth argument:

```
id center = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(center,
                             NULL,
                             callback,
                             CFSTR("kCTMessageReceivedNotification"),
                             NULL,
                             CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

As of iOS 8 you can't pass `NULL` as notification name to recieve all CoreTelephony notifications. Now you must tell it exactly which notifications you want to observe.

**8.3 UPDATE**

As of iOS 8.3 at least `kCTMessageReceivedNotification` requires entitlement to be received (probably the case for all notifications but don't know for sure)

```
<key>com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained</key>
<array>
    <string>spi</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me from a lot of digging :)

Comment: Since iOS 8.3, it seems that it's no more available.
I am trying with other notification that are still working on iOS 8.2 and prior. I don't know why, but it looks like Apple change the behavior of CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver. I tried to disassemble 8.2 & 8.3 CoreTelephony.framework, and all signatures seem to be the same. Do you have a workaround? Thank you.

Comment: @creker what value should I use to listen to phone calls, and where is this information listed or found? Thanks!

Comment: @creker How do you add the entitlement?

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 8.3, the CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver don't work any more.

Comment: @creker are you tested it with kCTMessageReceivedNotification on iOS 8.3?

Comment: @creker what's the value needed to listen for phone calls (to make phone call recording work)?

Comment: @creker, how i can add this entitlement. its' for non jailbreak iPhone?

Comment: Sadly adding entitlements is possible only for jailbroken phones. To add entitlements you can use ldid tool to resign the app